# No default constructor exists error

Tags: c++, constructor

This is my .h file

```
#ifndef __cppProject__CheckingAccount__
#define __cppProject__CheckingAccount__

#include "Customer.h"
#include "Account.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class CheckingAccount : public Account {
private:
   int accountNumber;   // 9nnnn - n randomly generated (0-9)

public:
   /* The ctor sets the owner by passing it to the parent class. Randomly
    * generates the account number which always starts with a '9' and is
    * followed by four randomly generated numbers in the range 0-9.
    */

    CheckingAccount(const Customer& owner);


   int getAccountNumber() const;

   /* Since the Account version is pure, this one will add the Account     specific
    * fields (dateOpened, owner) using the standard format we have been using.
    * Refer to the screen capture for details.
    */
   virtual string toString() const;
};
#endif /* defined(__cppProject__CheckingAccount__) */
```

This is my .cpp file

```
#include "Customer.h"
#include "CheckingAccount.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

CheckingAccount::CheckingAccount(const Customer& owner) : Account(owner){
    this->accountNumber = 9999;

}

int CheckingAccount::getAccountNumber() const{
    return accountNumber;
}

string CheckingAccount::toString() const {
    stringstream o;


    o << " CheckingAccount: {" << Account::toString() << ", accountNumber="      << accountNumber << ", owner=Customer: { "
        << " }";
    return o.str();
}
```

I am attempting to instantiate a CheckingAccount in main and the compiler is underlining my Customer class I am passing the CheckingAccount constructor and telling me that there is no default constructor provided.

If I try and make a no arg constructor when I attempt to implement it in the CheckingAccount.cpp file it gives me the same error.

Obviously I am missing some fundamental piece of information about default constructors, but I'm not sure what it is. I didn't think I had to have a default constructor unless CheckingAccount is a parent class, and it is not. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Adding main, it is small and just has a few test cases.

```
#include "Bank.h"
#include <string>
#include "CheckingAccount.h"
#include "Customer.h"
#include "Account.h"

using namespace std;

int Main() {
    Bank bank;
    Customer adam("Adam", "Apple");
    Customer beatrice("Beatrice", "Bagel");
    Customer chris("Chris", "Cucumber");
    Customer temp;

    CheckingAccount(adam);



    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Show us the exact, complete error message.

Comment: Error: no default constructor exists for class "CheckingAccount"

Comment: It looks like you're missing a variable name in `CheckingAccount(adam);`.

Comment: I don't see how that is possible, not to be rude, but I just don't see. In my .h and .cpp files I have this constructor: CheckingAccount(const Customer& owner) this should take only one arg. In my main I pass it one Customer class, called adam in this case. I don't see the discrepancy

Comment: http://puu.sh/g5Ltw/700b8718d4.png

Comment: I expect it to instantiate a checkingaccount that I can then add to the bank class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not:

```
CheckingAccount(adam);
```

is the same as

```
CheckingAccount adam;
```

but what you wanted is

```
CheckingAccount adams_account(adam);
```

Comment: Wow did I derp that one up. Well thanks for the answer and sorry to bother you with such stupid problem. Now i'll go bang my head against a wall and feel stupid.